# Custom seek bar not showing the background color

Tags: android

I am using the following seekbar

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sbCardSpeed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"/>
```

seekbar_progress.xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_fill"
    />

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress_bg"
    />
</layer-list>
```

background_fill.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF" //white color
        android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:angle="90" />

</shape>
```

seekbar_progress_bg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#FF8400"  //orange color
        android:centerColor="#FF8400"
        android:endColor="#FF8400"
        android:angle="90" />

</shape>
```

The problem that the progress bar is one color which is the orange color. If I move the thumb it is still orange on both sides. The white background is not showing. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this....

**seekbar_progress.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:maxLevel="10000" android:drawable="@drawable/progress_horizontal_orange" />
</level-list>
```

**progress_horizontal_orange.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
           <gradient
                android:startColor="#ffffff"
                android:endColor="#ffffff"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                 android:startColor="#FF8400"
                 android:endColor="#FF8400"
                 android:angle="90"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: @Snake i have tested the above code..if it helps then let me know.

Comment: @Snake your code seems to be alright but i don't y it not works..i think in seekbar_progress.xml you should directly define shape rather using separate xmls...ty..:)

Comment: Apperently adding a "clip" made a difference